# Why is my script file executable on a virtual machine?

Tags: command-line, permissions, scripts, chmod

I have ubuntu installed on a virtual machine in Windows. There when I run a script I just type sudo `./blabla.sh` in the terminal to run it.

Then I installed ubuntu from same iso file directly on a laptop, so it is not a virtual machine.

When I run the same script: sudo `./blabla.sh`, it says command not found. Then if I do `chmod +x blabla.sh` then I can run it.

Why is there this difference between the two?

Comment: Is it only "user" executable, and so root doesn't see the exec bit?

Comment: It is possibly because you are using sudo for the second one? Did you mean to type that difference?

Comment: Yea sorry it was supose to be sudo on both. @ben schwartz Hm, I will look in to that. If I don't use sudo it just says permission denied but with it it says command not found. And I am in the correct folder.

Comment: Try `ls -l` to get the perms

Comment: Whats the permission of `blabla.sh` in your virtual machine?

Comment: Thanks, I did ls -l and all the executables (compiled c files) says "-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root and my script file says -rwxrwxr-x 1 david david. Well the script file can run after I did chmod -x which means I made it executable. On my virtual machine the script has -rwxrwxrwx without any "manual" changes.

Comment: Hm, maybe I can run chmod on the whole folder to solve this. It doesn't answer the question but it is a solution on the problem that led to the question. Sorry, linux isn't my forte.

Comment: Are the script files on the two machines located in exactly the same location within their respective filesystems? it looks like the script on the VM is inheriting its permissions from the mount - that can happen, for example, if the script is in a directory that is shared from the Windows host.

Comment: Did you run -x or +x, the - would remove executability

Comment: +x Sorry for typing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo` needs at least one execute bit set to execute the file i.e. you need to set the execute bit for (at least) user or group or others. If no execute bit is set you can't execute the file as `sudo ./script`.

This example will make you clear:

```
$ ls -l test_scr 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 30 May  4 03:50 test_scr

$ sudo ./test_scr
sudo: ./test_scr: command not found

$ ./test_scr
bash: ./test_scr: Permission denied

$ chmod u+x test_scr 

$ sudo ./test_scr
Hello world

$ ./test_scr
Hello world
```

Also note that you don't need to make the file executable, you can run the file as an argument to the shell binary to execute it:

```
$ bash test_scr 
Hello world

$ sudo bash test_scr 
Hello world
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! I don't know why I had different permission on my two computers but it doesn't matter, the problem is solved.